# Probably a basic AF request. for i in range (modified)

Tags: raspbian

Trying to be the half-term hero I know I can be. I have a Pimoroni Blinkt unit that I'm running a `for i in range` command on creating an endless loop.

That's cool, but how do I modify the code to make the light as much like kit's front light from knight rider...

Current code:

```
while True:
    for i in range(8):
        clear()
        set_pixel(i, 255, 0, 0)
        show()
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Peter, Welcome and nice to meet you.  Ah, let me see.  I don't quite understand your single statement. It would help if you can show us a longer list of your program, and sprinkle a little bit more comments here and there.  Happy half-term holiday.  Cheers.

Comment: PS - Please let us know if you are using the same references list below, and if you are using any of their examples as a temple to write your "for i in range" program: References: (1) "Pimoroni Blinkt! Eight super-bright RGB LED indicators that are ideal for adding visual notifications to your Raspberry Pi without breaking the bank! £5.40":
https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/blinkt,

(2) "Pimoroni/blinkt GitHub python program library":
https://github.com/pimoroni/blinkt,

(3) "Pimoroni/blinkt GitHub python program library"
https://github.com/pimoroni/blinkt/tree/master/examples.

Comment: If you look in the example code in the github repo (https://github.com/pimoroni/blinkt/tree/master/examples) try running larson.py

Comment: Hey guys, so this is what I was working off of, will give larson a go - https://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/sandyj/getting-started-with-blinkt

Comment: Hi Peter, Oh my goodness, just give Larson a go, and that's it?  How can such a lazy guy become a half-term hero?  In my ninja opinion, to be a hero, you need to do harder homework at three times more than say, the following: (1) Try ALL the 20+ Blinkt examples. (2) Understand and MEMORIZE all the technical terms. Eg, you should be able to smoothly explain what is "HSV", and how is it defferent from "RGB", (3) , / to continue, ...

Comment: (3) Understand EVERY statement of every example, (4) Write higher level functions than those in Blinkt.  For example, define a superHero function called "superSetPixel", so you can say "superPixel('SeventhLed, 'NavyBlue')" instead of stupidly, nonheroly, "set_pixel(i, 255, 0, 0)".  To do this you need to learn and practise how to use "dictionary", "list", and "tuple" data structure which heroes practise everyday (yes, like Panda GungFu!). (a) One comment on Pimoroni Blint: I skimmed the Blinkt tutorial and found PirateNinja more newbie friendly than Lada Ada, / ton continue, ...

Comment: (b) One suggestion: Use Thonny to run your python code, because Thonny makes a hero sooner than terminal commands. Cheers!